# php vs code project to aws apache server file permissions

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, apache, server, chmod

I try to set up a server in AWS

I have 2 folders in the www Folder of the apace server.

www/userdata
www/WebContent

How do i have to set the file permissions for the WebContent folder.

I think when the server is serving the php page it doesn't allow the php page (php script) to fetch the data from the /userdata folder.

So the pages in the webcontent server are readable by everyone.

The /userdata folder is not readable by everyone.

The php page gets the date from the /userdata folder just when the /userdata folder is readble by everyone.

This is my fist time trying to set up a server without vs code.

How do i have to set the permissions or group or what ever to get this work.

Thanks for the answers.

benni

Comment: if it's not shared hosting, might as well use lxd or docker to isolate projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to set the document root of the apache server to /WebContent
now just the server side script can access the userdata because on the other hand only the document root can be accessed from outside. The date is not accessible from outside but the php page is.

Bye

Benni